# syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: drush

I am tring to get DRUSH (drush-master) up and running on a CentOS release 6.8 (Final) virtual server using PHP version 5.6.22. I will copy the php & DRUSH outputs below including the final error message:

Looking through the forums there is mention of the cause being an outdated version of PHP. However, I've checked the requirements and am pretty sure these versions should be compatible.

```
[server2 drush]# which drush
/usr/bin/drush
[server2 drush]# ls -lart /usr/bin/drush
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Sep  2 16:05 /usr/bin/drush -> /usr/local/drush/drush-master/drush*
[server2 drush]# /usr/bin/php56 --version
PHP 5.6.22 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2016 15:31:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
[server2 drush]# /usr/bin/php56 /usr/bin/drush
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /usr/local/drush/drush-master/includes/preflight.inc on line 248

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error you are seeing implies that you are actually running php 5.3.  I can see that /usr/bin/php56 is version 5.6.22, but does `$(which php)` really point to /usr/bin/php56? Double-check your $PATH.

Comment: Thanks for your help Greg. $(which php) does indeed point to an older version of php but I am manually parsing DRUSH though the 5.6 binary as follows: /usr/bin/php56 /usr/bin/drush

Comment: I think you have to do `DRUSH_PHP=/usr/bin/php56 /usr/bin/drush`